# No srvflx adress with Ubuntu and Puppeteer

Tags: ubuntu, webrtc, puppeteer

#### What I want todo

Use https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/ to gather a srvflx candicate.

#### Problem:

Cant receive srvflx candicate on Ubuntu Server(Linux). Works on Windows.

#### Step to reproduce:

OS Ubuntu 19.04 installation

- `sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`
- `sudo ufw disable`
- `curl ipecho.net/plain` // Returns a pingable ip

Setup Puppeteer:

- `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_13.x | sudo -E bash - && sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`
- `mkdir -p /tmp/puppeteertest && cd /tmp/puppeteertest && npm init`
- `npm i puppeteer --save`
- Install all libs listed here https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#chrome-headless-doesnt-launch-on-unix

  - `sudo apt-get install -y gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget`
- vi index.js // Create index.js with code below

```js
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

    (async () => {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
        args: [
          "--no-sandbox",
          "--disable-features=WebRtcHideLocalIpsWithMdns",
          "--disable-setuid-sandbox"
        ]
      });

      const pages = await browser.pages();
      const page = pages[0];
      await page.goto('https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/');
      // Start gathering
      await page.click("#gather");
      await page.waitFor(5000);

      // Scrape candidates
      const respItems = [];
      const tableContainer = await page.$('#candidatesBody');
      const trsElem = await tableContainer.$$('tr');

      for (let trElem of trsElem) {
        const dataList = await trElem.$$eval('td', tdsElem => tdsElem.map(td => td.innerText));
        respItems.push({
          time: dataList[0],
          compoment: dataList[1],
          type: dataList[2],
          foundation: dataList[3],
          protocol: dataList[4],
          address: dataList[5],
          port: dataList[6],
          priority: dataList[7],
        });
      };

      console.log(JSON.stringify(respItems, null, "\t"));
      await browser.close();
      process.exit(0);
    })();
```

Run

- `node index.js`

Output Windows

```
[
        {
                "time": "0.009",
                "compoment": "rtp",
                "type": "host",
                "foundation": "1879246603",
                "protocol": "udp",
                "address": "[LOCAL IP]",
                "port": "55810",
                "priority": "126 | 30 | 255"
        },
        {
                "time": "0.028",
                "compoment": "rtp",
                "type": "srflx",
                "foundation": "842163049",
                "protocol": "udp",
                "address": "[PUBLIC IP]",
                "port": "55810",
                "port": "55810",
                "priority": "126 | 30 | 255"
        },
        {
                "time": "0.028",
                "compoment": "rtp",
                "type": "srflx",
                "foundation": "842163049",
                "protocol": "udp",
                "address": "[PUBLIC IP]",
                "port": "55810",
                "priority": "100 | 30 | 255"
        },
        {
                "time": "0.110",
                "compoment": "Done"
        },
        {
                "time": "0.112"
        }
]
```

Output Ubuntu

```
    [
            {
                    "time": "0.007",
                    "compoment": "rtp",
                    "type": "host",
                    "foundation": "3461618340",
                    "protocol": "udp",
                    "address": "[PUBLIC IP]",
                    "port": "45743",
                    "priority": "126 | 30 | 255"
            },
            {
                    "time": "0.109",
                    "compoment": "Done"
            },
            {
                    "time": "0.111"
            }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your machine is configured with a public IP and not behind NAT (which is what the host candidate for ubuntu suggests) there will be no srflx candidate returned as the serverreflexive address is the same as the host address. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8445#section-5.1.3 for details.